# Custom authorization in Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-authentication

I am just a newbie with Django, python. I try to build 1 simple API Collection include CRUD basic, and authentication, authorization.

I have 1 simple Views like:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsUser])
def get_test(request : Request):
 return JsonResponse({"message": "success"}, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and IsUser is:

```
class IsUser(IsAuthenticated):
  def has_permission(self, request : Request, view):
    token = request.query_params.get('token')
    if token:
      role = jwt.decode(token.split(" ").__getitem__(1), key="secret_key",algorithms="HS256").get('role')
    if role == 'User':
        return True
    else:
        return False
  return False
```

My purpose wants to parse the JWT token and authorization based on that. I wonder don't know if my way is really correct? Can anyone give me some comments as well as documentation to better understand this issue? I don't use any other lib because I want to code by myself at first to understand the flow.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Does what you have work?

Comment: @Trent Yes, it works well. But I confused if my code is right and follows the flow code of Django framework. Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the default JWT authentication of DRF then permission class `IsAuthenticated` will verify the the token for you and instead of specifying token in query parameter specify in headers.

However, if you want to allow a specific type(role) of user to access your endpoint. Then create a subclass of `BasePermission` class as show in the example.

Then simply add `IsAuthenticated` in `@permission_classes([IsUser & IsAuthenticated])` to make it work.

Again, this would work only if you are using the default `Group` model.

Here is how you can import it `from django.contrib.auth.models import Group`

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

USER = 'USER'

class IsUser(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view, user=None):
        if not user:
            user = request.user
        return USER in [role.name for role in user.groups.filter()]
```

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand your opinion. About models, I use my own model named "User". About JWT token, I use jwt lib to generate a token based on my user information and my secret key. That why I must decode my token and check the role to access the endpoint.
I have tried to make my IsUser class extend BasePermission but my request doesn't reach has_permission method.

Comment: Is your mean is if I want to custom authentication and authorization, I must create 2 class: 1 for IsAuthenticated for authenticating, 1 for BasePermission for checking role from token to access endpoint?

Comment: Yes, the better approach would be to create a class to validate `token` and the separate classes for each role. This will help you have a fine grain access control for your endpoints.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks for your support!